# Segmentation fault when writing to file in c

Tags: c, windows, segmentation-fault

I've ran out of hope and ideas. I've been trying to debug this simple code, which is supposed to create a simple table in a file, for 3 days. I always get a segmantation fault when running it. I'm new to c but I know what a segmentation fault is. I just can't seem to fix it here. When running the compiled code, it does create an empty file with the correct name, but then the fault happens, and I stay with a new but completely empty file. So the problem, I guess, is somewhere between fopen and the first fprintf. Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void calc23(float x, float *f1, float *f2){
    *f1 = pow(x,2)-4.0*x+8.0;
    *f2 = pow(x,3)+2.0*x;
}

void main(){
    FILE *datf;
    datf = fopen("mydatatable.data", "w");
    float *f1, *f2;
    float r = -2.0;
    for(int i=1; i<100; i++){
        calc23(r, f1, f2);
        fprintf(datf, "%f %f %f \n", r, *f1, *f2);
        r += (4.0/99.0);
    }
    fclose(datf);
}
```

Comment: can i ask f1, f2 and point to what ? you not init it.as result and access violation (segmentation fault not windows word)

Comment: `float f1, f2; calc23(r, &f1, &f2);  fprintf(datf, "%f %f %f \n", r, f1, f2);` probably must be

Comment: there are only two valid signatures for the function: `main()`  1) `int main( void )` and 2) `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`  regardless of what Visual studio' allows

Comment: the function: `pow()` uses all `double` values. but all the variables in the posted code a of type `float`.  You might try using `powf()` and change all the literals to `float` or changing all the variables to `double`

Comment: regarding: `float *f1, *f2;`  these are declared as pointers, but they are never set to point to memory that the application owns.  to statements like: `*f2 = pow(x,3)+2.0*x;` are setting some random memory location (what ever happened to be on the stack where the variables (f1 and f2) are located.  This is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event. (as you have seen)

Comment: Note: in C, a `float` literal is defined with a trailing `f`.  Without the trailing `f` the literal is a `double`

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 1):

your pointers to float `f1` and `f2` are not initialized.
Make them simple float variables and pass them with the address operator

```
float f1, f2;
calc23(x, &f1, &f2);
printf("..", f1, f2);
```

Comment: This worked indeed, thank you so much (and to @RbMm who commented same)! I don't understand why the original code didn't work though...

Comment: the part in `calc23()` starting with `*f1 = pow...` was dereferencing an uninitialized pointer causing access violation.

Comment: by passing `&f1` to the function, the `f1` in `calc23` is a valid pointer to your float variable somewhere on your process' stack.

Answer (score 1):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. does not seg fault, as there is no undefined behavior to cause a seg fault
3. properly checks for errors from system functions
4. documents why each header file is included
5. corrects the problems listed in the comments to the question
6. chose to use `powf()` rather than `pow()` so all values (and literals) have type `float`

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // fopen(), fclose(), fwrite(), FILE
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <math.h>    // powf()

// prototypes
void calc23(float x, float *f1, float *f2);


int main( void )
{
    FILE *datf = fopen("mydatatable.data", "w");
    if( !datf )
    {
        perror( "fopen to write mydatatable.data failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    float f1;
    float f2;
    float r = -2.0f;

    for(int i=1; i<100; i++)
    {
        calc23(r, &f1, &f2);
        fprintf(datf, "%f %f %f \n", r, f1, f2);
        r += (4.0f/99.0f);
    }
    fclose(datf);
}


void calc23(float x, float *f1, float *f2)
{
    *f1 = powf(x,2.f)-4.0f*x+8.0f;
    *f2 = powf(x,3.f)+2.0f*x;
}
```

The first few lines of the output of the program:

```
-2.000000 20.000000 -12.000000 
-1.959596 19.678400 -11.444072 
-1.919192 19.360065 -10.907337 
-1.878788 19.044994 -10.389402
```

The last few line of the output of the program:

```
1.838385 4.026119 9.889888 
1.878789 4.014692 10.389421 
1.919193 4.006530 10.907358 
1.959597 4.001633 11.444093
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me troubleshoot and solve my similar issue!

Answer (score 0):

simple debugging the code:
 f1 and f2 are not initialized